# gsoap 2.8.15 SSL Support

Tags: c++, build, makefile, gsoap

I'm attempting to write a gsoap client on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using gsoap 2.8.15. From what I have read from another S.O. post (now which I cannot find), I'm supposed to make gsoap with the following command:

> make secure

However, there appears to be no rule to make target 'secure'.
This appears to be the documented way to enable ssl support in gsoap.  Does anybody have any tricks to make this work?

Ultimately, I need to run wsdl2h on a remotely hosted wsdl file over SSL to generate my client code.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only interested in generating code with the WSDL, you can download it manually with cURL or wget (which will both likely already include SSL support). Once saved locally, wsdl2h can deal with the local file without a problem.

Obviously, you'll probably want to include SSL support when you're building your applications and linking gSOAP. For what it's worth, SSL is enabled by default if you're manually building gSOAP from source. You have to disable it with `./configure --disable-ssl`.

Comment: I ended up manually downloading the wsdl file.  Thanks for your help